# Cannot use Observable as DataSource for MatTable , appears empty

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I've been trying to use an array of products that's being returned by subscribing to the corresponding service.
It works fine when it comes to displaying the objects properties on a list or something similar but I've been struggling to use the Material component data-table. 
I tried to do it by instantiating a new MatTableDataSource with the products array as an argument and to use try dynamic datasource by using the Observable directly but no success so far, the table is empty and the console is silent.

Here is the service :

```
import { IProduct } from './../interfaces/IProduct';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ProductService {
  productUrl = "https://localhost:44355/product/getproducts";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl);
  }

 }
```

The TypeScript file :

```
import { ProductService } from './../../services/product.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { IProduct } from 'src/app/interfaces/IProduct';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';


@Component({
  selector: "app-product",
  templateUrl: "./product.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./product.component.css"]
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  public products = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['productId', 'displayName', 'price', 'stockQuantity'];
  dataSource = new ProductDataSource(this.productService);

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getProducts()
      .subscribe(
      response => {
        this.products = response.items;
        console.log(this.products);
      }
    );
  }
}
export class ProductDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.productService.getProducts();
  }
  disconnect() { }
}
```

And lastly the HTML

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="productId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.productId}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="displayName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nom </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.displayName}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Prix </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.price}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="stockQuantity">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Quantité </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.stockQuantity}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Also I don't know if it's linked but at the subscription :

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.productService.getProducts()
          .subscribe(
          response => {
            this.products = response.items;
            console.log(this.products);
          }
        );
```

UPDATE Incoming Data from API :

```
{"items":[{"productId":1,"name":"B12BocalVerreSoufflé","description":"Bocal en verre soufflé à la main et son couvercle en liège. Très bon état.","price":13.00,"status":100,"stockQuantity":1,"displayName":"Bocal en verre soufflé                                                                                                                                                                                  ","productFlags":0},{"productId":2,"name":"B30AssietteCampagne","description":"Lot de 4 assiettes en céramique. Décor en fleurs fait à la main. Bon état.","price":16.00,"status":100,"stockQuantity":36,"displayName":"Assiettes campagne                                                                                                                                                                                      ","productFlags":1},{"productId":3,"name":"B41BocalPommeHenkel","description":"Bocal en verre et couvercle en plastique. Décor pomme rouge de la marque Henkel des années 70. Bon état.","price":200.00,"status":100,"stockQuantity":11,"displayName":"Bocal pomme rouge Henkel                                                                                                                                                                                ","productFlags":0}
```

And the interface IProduct :

```
export interface IProduct {
  name: string;

  price: number;

  productId: number;

  description: string;

  status: number;

  stockQuantity: number;

  displayName: string;

  productFlags: number;

  xmlData: string;

  blob: any;
}
```

UPDATE 2 : Stackblitz for the app : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6xjfmf?embed=1&file=src/app/product.service.ts

**FINAL UPDATE AND SOLUTION** : So part of the solution was given by Deborah bellow, I had to use products as the datasource directly :

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="products" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

Also I still had the issue of not being able to get the items part of my response when subscribing, as it was considered an object and simply doing response.items wasn't working because items wasn't a property of Object.

The solution was easy I just had to do it in two steps :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getProducts()
      .subscribe(
      response => {
        this.products = response;
        this.products = this.products.items;
        console.log(this.products);
      }
    );
  }
```

There you go , I hope it helps somebody in the same situation. 
Thanks to Deborah!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code:

```
  getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl);
  }
```

Is giving you back an `Observable<IProduct[]>`

**UPDATE**

If the response coming back from your server actually contains the product array under items, then obtain the products from the items in the service code:

```
  getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl)
       .pipe(
         tap(response => console.log(response)),
         map(response => response.items);
       )
  }
```

This should then return the items *as* the `IProduct[]`. You could also throw the `tap` operator in there temporarily just to confirm what your `response` looks like.

**END UPDATE**

So in your subscribe:

```
    this.productService.getProducts()
      .subscribe(
      response => {
        this.products = response.items;
        console.log(this.products);
      }
    );
```

`response` is of type `IProduct[]`. It has no `items` property.

Try changing the above code to this:

```
    this.productService.getProducts()
      .subscribe(
      products => {
        this.products = products;
        console.log(this.products);
      }
    );
```

And you should get your list of products.

Then I assume you need to set the datasource property to the returned list of products:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="products" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

NOTE: All of the above ignores the `dataSource`property in the class and your `ProductDataSource` class. If you can get the above to work, we can see how we can modify it to use your more generalized code.

This:

```
dataSource = new ProductDataSource(this.productService);
```

Will never retrieve any data because it does not subscribe. (Unless the mat-table has some magic that handles Observables and subscribes for you? No ... it doesn't. I just looked at the examples in the docs and they all subscribe manually.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer , this is the issue I had before, I had something like what you just wrote but it was returning me an object Object needs to be turned into an array, and in my Json this array is called items which contains my product, if I don't put items I get something I cannot use. I don't think I was clear enough in the post but I can have a list of products my property is initialized and I can use it, the problem is I can't use it to populate the mat-table in particular.

Comment: Can you add to your question a bit of what your incoming data looks like? And the definition of IProduct?

Comment: See the update marked near the top of my reply above.

Comment: Alright I just updated my post and tried to modify my service but when it comes to the mapping it does still say that items isn't a property of IProduct as usual, except in that case Angular doesn't compile and I get a 404 at the start, I'll add the IProduct in update right now

Comment: Be sure to add *items* to the *service* and remove it from the *component*. Any way you can simplify the piece of the app you are working on and post it to stackblitz? Then I could help more directly with your specific code.

Comment: I made sure of that, it's in the service code at this line : map(response => response.items); that I get the error. I deleted it from the ts file , I'm trying to put it on stackblitz right now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187350/discussion-between-distoch-and-deborahk).

Comment: I'm out for the evening ..  but I'd guess we can't do this: `get<IProduct[]>`, since the response is not an array of products. Try taking the generic parameter off.

Comment: I tried to look at your stackblitz ... but it seems to be missing the UI. There is no code in app.component.html. Also, the link does not seem to be the correct link as I can't fork or work with the project. Under the `share` menu be sure to copy and paste here the *first* URL (Editor URL) so I can edit the files. THANKS!

Comment: Hey I finally managed to find what's wrong, sorry couldn't really work on it the last days, part of the solution was to use product directly as datasource as you mentionned but I had to find a way to use directly items in the json response, I'll update my post and close the question, thanks for you help !